# Python: Asynchronous send/receive on normal socket and a http connection

Tags: python, ajax, sockets, asynchronous

I have a task that needs to accept msgs (normal strings) at the frontend, do some processing and convert those msgs to http requests that need to be sent to a backend server. So there are essentially two endpoints - frontend is a normal BSD socket. Backend is a urllib.HTTPconnection.  Responses go the reverse way. However, this is not a request-response scenario. I could have a completely out of order req1->req2->resp2->req4->req3->resp3->resp1 ... type of asynchronous scenario.  So I can't just do a:

```
msg = socketFrontEnd.recv()
... process msg and make 'Request' 
resp, content = httpBackEnd.request("http://example.org", "PUT", body=Request)   
... process resp and make 'Response'
socketFrontEnd.send(Response)
```

I need something more like a polling mechanism:

```
While(True):
   readysockets = select(SocketFrontEnd, httpBackEnd)

   if readysockets has SocketFrontEnd:
       msg = socketFrontEnd.recv()
       process and send request to httpBackEnd(...)

   if readysockets has httpBackEnd:
       resp = httpBackEnd(...)
       process and send response to socketFrontEnd()
```

However, to the best of my knowledge I can't put a http connection in some kind of a select statement. Even if that were possible, how do you separately send and receive from a httpconnection (instead of using the single "http.request(..)" command).

What if I send some ajax request on the httpconnection, will that callback in ajax request be run if I'm blocked on socketFrontEnd ? That is, can we do something like:

```
while(True):
    msg = socketFrontEnd.recv() <-- blocked
    ... process and make 'Request'
    ajax('callback_function', Request, 'http://backendserver.com')


Callback_function(resp):
    ... process and make Response
    socketFrontEnd.send(Response)
```

Comment: AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML, I'm pretty sure that's not what you want. Perhaps you just meant "asynchronous HTTP request"?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the asyncore module of Python suitable for your problem? Or a framework like Twisted?

Comment: I hear twisted can be quite a handful to learn - so if that's the only option left, I will have to do it. I don't know about asyncore. I will look it up (still a python beginner here) .. tried following the example of HTTPclient on docs.python.org but its implications hasn't sunk in yet. Will try again.